# adding the default filter apparently "disables" the filter raw

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to display the raw value of a variable, if this one is empty, the default value `N/A` should be shown instead.

The code below doesn't work, but it shows even the html tags

```
{% set my_var = '<b>hello world!!</b>' %}
{{ my_var | default('N/A') | nl2br | raw }}
```

As strange as this may seem, the following code works, knowing that I just removed the `default` filter

```
{% set my_var = '<b>hello world!!</b>' %}
{{ my_var | nl2br | raw }}
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
{% set my_var = '<b>hello world!!</b>' %}

{{ my_var|default('N/A')|raw|nl2br }}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, obviously, and it didn't work for me...does it work for you??

Comment: Could you explain why this makes a difference?

Comment: Because [nl2br](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html) pre-escapes the string for you, thats why `raw` doesn't have any effect because it's escaped